# Android emulator location map is not loading

Tags: android, android-emulator, maui

The location emulator used to work perfectly without any problem all of a sudden the map is no longer loading as seen in the screenshot attached bellow i tried resetting emulator install sdk updates delete and install image but without any success
any help would be great [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an known issue for the native android: [Can't see google maps inside Android Emulator Extended Controls](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228201899).

And at the end of the comments, it can be resolved by updating the Android SDK Platform-Tools and Android  Emulator.

For the Visual Studio, you can go to the **Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager -> Tools** to update the Android SDK Platform-Tools and Android  Emulator.

Or you can just downlaod the android studio and use the emulator in it.

**Update:**

Update the Visual Studio will resolve the problem.

Comment: Hello thank you for your help this is what I did at first updating my Android 33 version did not fix the issue
I did manage to fix it later on by updating Visual Studio and then i was able to add Android 34 image which fixed my issue

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to know you have resolved the problem. And I have updated the answer. @HuSaad